# Why is my cout executing all at once in though cin should be read inbetween?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ code and when I input anything but a number for any `cin` it automatically executes the rest of the `cout`.
Basically, if I wanted to name the first fruit "Apple", it would execute all of the other `cout`. If I named it only with numbers the other `cout` would be fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Fruit {
    char Name;
    double Weight;
    int Calories;
};

int main(){
    struct Fruit TodaysFruit;
    struct Fruit FruitA;
    struct Fruit FruitB;
    struct Fruit FruitC;
    struct Fruit FruitD;
    struct Fruit FruitE;

    cout << "Enter Name For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitA.Name;
    cout << "Enter Weight For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitA.Weight;
    cout << "Enter Calories for Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitA.Calories;
    //break
    cout << "Enter Name For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitB.Name;
    cout << "Enter Weight For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitB.Weight;
    cout << "Enter Calories for Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitB.Calories;
    //break
    cout << "Enter Name For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitC.Name;
    cout << "Enter Weight For Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitC.Weight;
    cout << "Enter Calories for Fruit" << endl;
    cin >> FruitC.Calories;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Do you name the fruit with a single letter, like allowed by your code? Or do you try to name it with multiple letters? "Apple" is of course multiple letters... Did you try using `string Name` instead of `char Name`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow by the way. Quite a nice question for a first try - good work. Nevertheless, please take the [tour] at your convenience, it is appreciated by other users.

Comment: In C++ you don't have to use ``struct`` keyword when instantiating an object of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you input "Apple" for

```
cin >> FruitA.Name;
```

Then "A" will go into the single character `Name` in your struct.
"pple" will remain in input stream and will fail to be read into all the following numbers, causing the input stream to go into error state and all subsequent reads will fail (credits Pete Becker).

To fix, replace

```
char Name;
```

with

```
std::string Name;
```

You need to `#include <string>` to support that (credits Ap31).
The `std::` (a good input by Peter, credits) will make sure that the intended string is used, even if any active `using` would make confusion possible.

Comment: `string` is ambiguous (since it can refer to something in any namespace, if there is a valid `using` in effect).  `std::string` is specific.

Comment: @Peter There is a `using namespace std;` with no mention of a `string` type, so `string` is specific enough IMO
.

Comment: you would also want to add `#include <string>`

Comment: After the first failure the stream will be in an error state and all subsequent reads will fail. So `cin >> FruitB.Name;` will fail; it will not read `'p'`.